# Tokbox archiving callback url always returns null on .Net

Tags: c#, .net, opentok, tokbox

I have a .Net server with .Net SDK tokbox sdk.

I need to know when archiving has been uploaded to my AWS S3 bucket, and in order to do that I need to receive JSON callback url.

Being my url https://company.com/home/archivingvideo I am trying, on HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ArchivingVideo(String param)
{

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ArchivingVideo(Object param)
{


[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ArchivingVideo(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject param)
{
```

String function receives null parameter. 
Object function receives {} paramenter.
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject is not called

Do you know which type should I try to get callback information? I have tried sending me a JSON file with POSTMAN and I receive a String.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the archive URL, you need to poll the server, because the time it takes to upload to S3 is variable. You can, for instance, do a GET every 5 seconds, and, eventually, you will get the download URL.

Comment: On TokBox project configuration you can provide a url and they send you a POST, with a Json, whenever S3 has finished uploading.

I could call S3 every 5 minutes, but if I have a cleaner tool I would prefer to use it.